# When I am trying to get live stream from youtube using opencv and camgear I am getting the following error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, live-streaming

I want to get the live stream from youtube, and for that, I have used opencv along with the package vidgear. But while running the code, I am getting the following error. I am sure that there is no problem with the URL.

I have tried with pafy and streamlink. Even though both have given the result but after few frames, it was getting stuck and I want sequential frames without any pause.

```
import cv2
from vidgear.gears import CamGear
stream = CamGear(source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIk_6OuYkSo", y_tube =True,  time_delay=1, logging=True).start() # YouTube Video URL as input

while True:

    frame = stream.read()
    if frame is None:
        break

    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)


    key = cv2.waitKey(30) 

    if key == ord("q"):

        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
stream.stop()
```

Error output ::

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CamfyVision\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vidgear\gears\camgear.py", line 120, in __init__
    print('Extension: {}'.format(_source.extension))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DronrStream.py", line 4, in <module>
    stream = CamGear(source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIk_6OuYkSo", y_tube =True,  time_delay=1, logging=True).start() # YouTube Video URL as input
  File "C:\Users\CamfyVision\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vidgear\gears\camgear.py", line 125, in __init__
    raise ValueError('YouTube Mode is enabled and the input YouTube Url is invalid!')
ValueError: YouTube Mode is enabled and the input YouTube Url is invalid!
```

Answer (score 1):

@Adithya Raj I'm the author of **[VidGear](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Video Processing python library.**

This error is because of a bug with YouTube live streams and is already been resolved in this [commit](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/commit/03ec55487855a76c9faee464e11b39492896179e). Kindly update vidgear as follows:

```sh
pip install -U vidgear
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i was try to run your script and i got error in URL link but when i replace with other URL link then you're script works fine no error. have look pics

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know that my code will work for normal youtube videos, but I have mentioned in my question that I want live stream from the youtube. So do you have any idea to solve the problem with loading the live video.